# highlighting the max valued bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have created a bar chart
all i want is how i can get the higlight of max bar

Problem
The problem is that i have to highlight the bar with max value
im using the d3v6 to create the chart

below is the current  code which im using to create bar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
          
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
          
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
      
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Parse the Data
//d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/7_OneCatOneNum_header.csv").then( function(data) {

// X axis
final_data=
{
"total":10,
"plotting_data":[
{slider: "01", Value: "3"},
{slider: "02", Value: "5"},
{slider: "03", Value: "6"},
{slider: "04", Value: "4"},
{slider: "05", Value: "5"},



]
}
data=final_data["plotting_data"]

console.log("data:-",data)
const x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(data.map(d => d.slider))
  .padding(0.2);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0))
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)rotate(0)") //rotate(0) it can be used to tilt the text
    .style("text-anchor", "center");//here we can specify the start end and center values

// Add Y axis
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, final_data['total']])
  .range([ height, 0]);
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0));

const rx =5;
const ry =5;

// Bars
var bars = svg.selectAll("mybar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  
bars.append("path")
    .attr("x", d => x(d.slider))
    .attr("y", d => y(d.Value))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", d => height - y(d.Value))
    .attr("fill", "#056DFF")
    .attr(
        "d",
        item => `
        M${x(item.slider)},${y(item.Value) + ry}
        a${rx},${ry} 0 0 1 ${rx},${-ry}
        h${x.bandwidth() - 2 * rx}
        a${rx},${ry} 0 0 1 ${rx},${ry}
        v${height - y(item.Value) - ry}
        h${-x.bandwidth()}Z
      `
      )
    
bars.append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
            .attr("y",  function (d) { 
            if (d.Value>=5/100*final_data['total']){
            
             return y(d.Value)+10;
            }
            else 
            {return y(d.Value)};
            })
            //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
            .attr("x", d => x(d.slider) +x.bandwidth()/2)
            .style("font-size", function (d) {
                
                return 10;
            })
            .style("font-family","sans-serif")
            .style('fill', 'white')
            
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.Value;
            })
            .style("text-anchor", "middle");





  svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
      .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("No of resources");      




  // text label for the x axis
  svg.append("text")             
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                           (height + margin.top + 20) + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Slider Value")
      .style('fill', 'black');
</script>
</body>
```

**Current Output**
[image]

**Expected Output**
[image]

**Any help or guidance will be a great help**
For any doubt regarding question comment below

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using your code. It adds a line to find the max value then adds a different fill if it matches the max. So the max bar is red.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Parse the Data
//d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/7_OneCatOneNum_header.csv").then( function(data) {

// X axis
final_data=
{
"total":10,
"plotting_data":[
{slider: "01", Value: "3"},
{slider: "02", Value: "5"},
{slider: "03", Value: "6"},
{slider: "04", Value: "4"},
{slider: "05", Value: "5"},



]
}
data=final_data["plotting_data"]

// Added this to find max
max = d3.max(data.map(d => d.Value))

console.log("data:-",data)
const x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([ 0, width ])
  .domain(data.map(d => d.slider))
  .padding(0.2);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0))
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)rotate(0)") //rotate(0) it can be used to tilt the text
    .style("text-anchor", "center");//here we can specify the start end and center values

// Add Y axis
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, final_data['total']])
  .range([ height, 0]);
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(0));

const rx =5;
const ry =5;

// Bars
var bars = svg.selectAll("mybar")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  
bars.append("path")
    .attr("x", d => x(d.slider))
    .attr("y", d => y(d.Value))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", d => height - y(d.Value))
    // Set the fill based on if its max
    .attr("fill", d => d.Value === max ? '#FF0000FF' :"#056DFF")
    .attr(
        "d",
        item => `
        M${x(item.slider)},${y(item.Value) + ry}
        a${rx},${ry} 0 0 1 ${rx},${-ry}
        h${x.bandwidth() - 2 * rx}
        a${rx},${ry} 0 0 1 ${rx},${ry}
        v${height - y(item.Value) - ry}
        h${-x.bandwidth()}Z
      `
      )
    
bars.append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
            .attr("y",  function (d) { 
            if (d.Value>=5/100*final_data['total']){
            
             return y(d.Value)+10;
            }
            else 
            {return y(d.Value)};
            })
            //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
            .attr("x", d => x(d.slider) +x.bandwidth()/2)
            .style("font-size", function (d) {
                
                return 10;
            })
            .style("font-family","sans-serif")
            .style('fill', 'white')
            
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.Value;
            })
            .style("text-anchor", "middle");





  svg.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
      .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("No of resources");      




  // text label for the x axis
  svg.append("text")             
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                           (height + margin.top + 20) + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Slider Value")
      .style('fill', 'black');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>

<div id="my_dataviz">
```